# ProgressEvent.PROGRESS not firing in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, preloader, loaderinfo

I trying to create a preloader for a game in Flash CS6. I've already slowed down the download speed to 1,2 kb but the ProgressEvent.PROGRESS is never fired. This is what I have:

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.ProgressEvent;
stop();

loaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onProgressMade);

function onProgressMade( progressEvent:ProgressEvent ):void {
trace( loaderInfo.bytesLoaded, loaderInfo.bytesTotal );
}
```

The stage stays blank but onProgressMade gets never called. Can someone point me in the right direction, please?

Comment: Do you load content from filesystem (they are loaded SYNCHRONOUS as far as I know)?

Comment: As LondonDrugs said you should probably post more code, such as what you're loading, how, or where you're getting your LoaderInfo from. As far as I can see this code is correct so the problem must be elswhere.

Comment: Well I have three frames where all my assets are being loaded in the second frame. The first frame holds the code mentioned above. I get no error whatsoever. There is no more code than that in the first frame.

Comment: go to advanced actionscript3.0 settings -> Export class frames -> set it to 2. then try.

Comment: To see if it's loading at all, add an event listener for the Event.COMPLETE event. If not then there's a problem with your loading in general, maybe Jegan's solution works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following this tutorial:   http://stephenscholtz.com/201110/single-movie-flash-preloading-as3

Comment: There were images, that's why I chose this as the correct answer ;-))

Comment: This one is very good as well: http://jeffkamerer.com/blog/2010/08/12/using-a-custom-preloader-loop-with-tlf-text/